# try-catch в constexpr?

Tags: c++, исключения, constexpr

Можно ли использовать обработку исключений в `constexpr` функциях и методах?

Comment: Нет. На это С++ пойтить не может... Впрочем, я тут уже накалывался на новейших стандартах - уточню,это по состоянию на C++14. Но не представляю возможность реализации механизма исключений в constexpr в принципе...

Comment: Вроде хотели в стандарт C++20 добавить такую возможность.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начиная с C++20 (так же известный как C++2a) в `constexpr` функции [можно включать](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) `try-catch` блок. Сделано это, как я понимаю, для унификации, чтобы не нужно было писать разные функции для ситуаций вычисления в процессе компиляции или рантайма. Ведь `constexpr` это ещё не гарантия того, что функция будет вычисляться в момент компиляции, а всего лишь разрешение такой возможности.

При этом использовать явный `throw` запрещено, т.к. это автоматически блокирует возможность функции вычисляться на этапе компиляции. Т.е. входит в противоречие с самой идеей `constexpr`.

Соответствующий proposal по разрешению `try-catch` в `constexpr` функциях можно найти [тут](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1002r0.pdf).